# Hiding and showing web element with CSS in dart?

Tags: html, css, hide, dart, show

I would love to learn how to hide and show elements in html using dart. I was thinking of using display:none; in CSS. But how would I change CSS values or write CSS in dart for different HTML tags?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [Element.hidden](https://api.dartlang.org/docs/channels/stable/latest/dart_html/Element.html#hidden) to indicate whether the element is not relevant to the page's current state.

If you want to use style :

```dart
element.style.display = 'none';
element.style.display = '';
```

If you want to use CSS classes :

```dart
element.classes.add('selected');
element.classes.toggle('isOnline');
element.classes.remove('selected');
```